# Getting lsetxattr errors using rsync with some files that have Apple resource forks

Tags: rsync, mac

I'm running a backup of a MacOS machine to a Linux server using rsync. There are a few files that give errors every time, and I'm trying to figure out how to deal with them. I'd like to not get these errors, or potentially find a way to log a warning and not error out when this happens, since the rest of the backup is fine.

There are two kinds of errors I'm getting, but both are occurring with lsetattr and a file with a  resource fork. (I think it's only some files with resource forks, not all of them, and the ones I've seen look to be image files).  One error looks like this:

> rsync: rsync_xal_set: lsetxattr(""/backup/Demo.boxer/Icon#015"","user.com.apple.ResourceFork") failed: Argument list too long (7)

The other is:

> rsync: rsync_xal_set: lsetxattr(""/backup/photo/market.JPG"","user.com.apple.ResourceFork") failed: No space left on device (28)

Here is the complete rsync command (it's part of a script file):

```
rsync -ax --delete --delete-excluded --filter="merge rsync_filter.rules"\
          --numeric-ids --protect-args --xattrs -M--fake-super -e "ssh -i ${ssh_key}"\
          --rsync-path="${remote_user_script_root}/rsync_wrapper.sh ${backup_path} ${backup_time}" \
          --info=progress2 --stats\
          --relative / $remote_user@$remote_server:"${backup_dir}"
```

I have run it both with and without the --protect-args flag. If I add the -A (acls) flag, a few files give different errors, but it's largely the same.

The Mac (sender) is running : rsync  version 3.2.2  protocol version 31
The remote server is running : rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31

Updating the version on the remote server is non-trivial, but could be done if it's certain to fix this.

Comment: That error message suggests the resource fork may be too large to be stored as an xattr;. Check the files' resource fork sizes, and compare with the limits in "Filesystem differences" section of the the [xattr(7) man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html).

Comment: I can manually fix the resource forks on these particular files, but I was looking to make sure one bad file doesn't break the backup script.I'm using btrfs on the server, so maybe fixing the node size would do it.